# Java streams on List<Object> get a property of any object matching filter()

Tags: java

I want to get the property of any object matching the filter() of the stream, but I am unable to.

```
transactionsList.stream()
    .filter(transaction -> transaction.getPayerIban() != null)
    .findFirst()
    //Here I get an Optional<Object>
    .ifPresent()
    .map(Transaction::getName)
```

I don't know what to do inside the `.ifPresent()` stream operation, but I want to get any transaction name of the matching transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ifPresent()`:

```
Optional<String> optionalName = transactionsList.stream()
    .filter(transaction -> transaction.getPayerIban() != null)
    .findFirst()
    .map(Transaction::getName);
```

Comment: (From one Andy T to another...)